# What is the rough concept behind the AOA object tracking?

Tags: azure-object-anchors

I am currently working on my Master Thesis, trying out different object detection/tracking SDKs for Hololens 2. Are you using some kind of ICP algorithm for detecting and tracking the objects? I assume that you are not using any geometry-based model tracking algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, AOA detects and tracks object by leveraging different kinds information on both object and the surrounding environment. This includes geometry data and some ICP algorithms.